# Javascript get values of different cell types inside a table row

Tags: javascript, dom

Good Evening, i write a script to get the value of any row that's clicked, but my problem is that any row contains different types of controls, it may be a text field `<input type="text" id="speed" />` and it may be a dropdown

```
    <select name="engineType">
       <option value="1">Manual</option>
       <option value="2">Automatic</option>
       <option value="3">Both</option>
    </select>
```

in the first case i will get the innerHtml, in the second case i will get the value (value of selected item) so how to check the type of each cell before deciding to get the value or innerHtml, here's the script:

```
function findRowNumber() {
    var rowIdx;
    var rowData = new Array();
    var table = document.getElementById('product_table');
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var selectedRow;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].onclick = function() {
            rowIdx = this.rowIndex;
            selectedRow = rows[rowIdx];
            for (var j = 1; j <11; j++) {
                var rowCell = selectedRow.cells[j].innerHTML;
                rowData.push(rowCellValue);
                alert(rowCellValue);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What types of controls do you want to filter based on?

Comment: i want to know if the cell is of type <select> or if it's of type<input type="text">

Comment: First, you'd never use `.innerHTML` to get the value of an input. Second, the word "cell" refers to the table cell, not the input. You need to get the input node that is inside the cell.

Comment: Use the selectedRow.cells[j].value to get the value. You will get value of select and input this way.

Comment: And just FYI, this is entirely unnecessary: `rowIdx = this.rowIndex; selectedRow = rows[rowIdx];` because `this` is already a reference to the row, so you don't need the `.rowIndex` to fetch what you already have.

Comment: @ДарияПечайко: That's not right. You can't get the value of an input directly from a table cell node. You need to get it from the input.

Comment: Yes, from input or select(in this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for, though as the system said, perhaps `.innerHTML` is not the best way of doing things.

```
for (var j = 1; j <11; j++) {
    var rowCell = selectedRow.cells[j];
    var inputElements;
    if((inputElements = rowCell.getElementByTagName("select")).length > 0)
    {
        // Do stuff for select
    }
    else if((inputElements = rowCell.getElementByTagName("input")).length > 0)
    {
        // Do stuff for input
    }

    rowData.push(rowCellValue);
    alert(rowCellValue);
}
```

Comment: Your `if(...)` will always be `true`. You should get the `[0]` index from the resulting collection.

Comment: Looks good to me. That'll give the entire collection to work with so it'll be handy if there's more than one select or input. If there could be both in a cell, you could just remove the `else`.

Comment: @CrazyCasta it doesn't enter the two if statements at all!!

Comment: Well, I would try displaying the innerHTML of rowCell right before the if's then. Because if there is a select or input inside the rowCell that's being selected then it should enter one of the two.